# Change content of multiple div's onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need help with some JavaScript to a product toggle page.

Basically, all I have a page with 3 div's.

```
#product-toggle
#product-image
#product-specs
```

The #product-toggle div has a menu with links to several products. When clicking on each product link, the #product-image and #product-specs content has to change to the actual product that will get clicked.

I've tried several div swap scripts, but they all only change 1 div, and not 2 as in my case. Also I can't use any solution where the content text is written INSIDE the JS. The content has to be written in a DIV (for easy customization in the CMS that I will be using).

Thanks in advance!

Also if jQuery can be avoided, that'll be great.

This is the HTML of the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" >
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Products</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="product-image">

        <div id="model-1-img"><img src="link/to/model-1/img.png" /></div>
        <div id="model-2-img"><img src="link/to/model-2/img.png" /></div>
        <div id="model-3-img"><img src="link/to/model-3/img.png" /></div>

    </div>

    <div id="product-toggle">
        <a href="#">Model 1</a> | <a href="#">Model 2</a> | <a href="#">Model 3</a>
    </div>

    <div id="product-specs">

        <div id="model-1-spec">
            <p>Specs of model 1</p>
        </div>

        <div id="model-2-spec">
            <p>Specs of model 2</p>
        </div>

        <div id="model-3-spec">
            <p>Specs of model 3</p>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you googled about it??And attach some of the code snippets you have tried so far?How is it expected to resolve this problem without jquery?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. http://whathaveyoutried.com? Please show us what you have so far. SO is not a code writing service, and you will get a better response if you provide evidence of your own work. Please see [the Help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: @Infinity, we managed quite well with vanilla javascript before jQuery arrived

Comment: @Infinity I believe I don't need jQuery for this, but If I do it's not a problem.

Comment: @freefaller Thanks. I've updated the question with the HTML of my code. Truth is, that I really can't code JS, and that's why I really need help, since I can't get any scripts I've copied out there to work with 2 divs changing content. This did work for me, but as I said only with 1 div. http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-34902.html

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use this, though I have not included it for images which I am sure you can do after looking at this example.

```
<div id="product-toggle">
    <h3> Click on any brand to know its specs: </h3>
    <h2 onclick="toggleContent('samsung')" style="color: blue">Samsung</h2>
    <h2 onclick="toggleContent('nokia')" style="color: blue">Nokia</h2>
    <h2 onclick="toggleContent('apple')" style="color: blue">Apple</h2>
</div>

<h3> Product Specifications </h3>
<div id="product-specs" style="color: brown; font-size: 25px"> </div>


  <script>
        var specs = {
            'samsung' : 'S5 is lastest Samsung Phone',
            'apple' : 'iPhone5 is latest Apple Phone',
            'nokia' : 'Nokia has started making Android phone'
        }
        function toggleContent(brand)
        {
            document.getElementById('product-specs').innerHTML = specs[brand];
        }

    </script>
```

Thank You

Comment: Thanks. How can I also change the img? I've tried this: onclick="toggleContent('samsung'+'samsung-img')" and added samsung-img to the var specs list. That don't work. So how can I change 2 div's on 1 click?

Answer (score 0):

you need to set a `onClick`-callback for each link.
The callback looks for the link's id and executes some business logic e.g fetching the data via ajax. 
then you should use

```
var specs = document.getElementById("#divId");
```

to write all your information inside the diff.

this is a very basic task, you dont need some scripts/libraries for this

Comment: Thanks, I've tried some javascript code that I found with an onclick="reveal('model-1-spec');" code, and it worked. But only on 1 div. I've tried doing something like this to the code, but without any luck: onclick="reveal('model-1-spec'+'model-1-img');"

Answer (score 0):

Here is the modified one with image toggle as well:

```
<div id="product-toggle">
    <h3> Click on any brand to know its specs: </h3>
    <h2 onclick="toggleContent('samsung')" style="color: blue">Samsung</h2>
    <h2 onclick="toggleContent('nokia')" style="color: blue">Nokia</h2>
    <h2 onclick="toggleContent('apple')" style="color: blue">Apple</h2>
</div>

<h3> Product Specifications </h3>
<div id="product-specs" style="color: brown; font-size: 25px"> </div>


<img src="" id="product-image">

 <script>
        var specs = {
            'samsung' : {desc: 'S5 is lastest Samsung Phone', src:'bear.png'},
            'apple' : {desc: 'iPhone5 is latest Apple Phone', src:'cat.png'},
            'nokia' : {desc: 'Nokia has started making Android phone', src:'chiken.png'}
        }
        function toggleContent(brand)
        {
            document.getElementById('product-specs').innerHTML = specs[brand].desc;
            document.getElementById('product-image').src = specs[brand].src;
        }

    </script>
```